# Change "perspective" of multi-dimension tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

```
|-- Car                                |-- Green     
|   |-- Audi                           |   |-- Car        
|   |   |-- Green                      |   |   `-- Audi           
|   |   |-- Blue                       |   `-- Bike             
|   |   `-- Red                        |       `-- BMW  
|   `-- BMW                            |-- Blue     
|       |-- Red                        |   `-- Car         
|       `-- Yellow     ==========>     |       `-- Audi     ==========>     etc.                 
`-- Bike                               |-- Red         
    |-- BMW                            |   |-- Car    
    |   |-- Yellow                     |   |   |-- Audi 
    |   |-- Blue                       |   |   `-- BMW
    |   `-- Green                      |   `-- Bike       
    `-- Honda                          |       `-- Honda       
        |-- Red                        `-- Yellow          
        `-- Yellow                         |-- Car         
                                           |   `-- BMW
                                           `-- Bike
                                               |-- BMW
                                               `-- Honda
```

I want to implement several "perspectives" in a tree builder, in a **generic fashion**.

There are 6 possible permutations of this tree, I've just drawn 2 of them.

**What I tried:**

- I'm using a generic tree structure, where every node knows its parent and children, and has a payload.
- Classes: `TreeBuilder`, `AbstractNode`, `VehicleNode`, `ColorNode`, `MakerNode`, and another ordered list of enums which defines the order of the levels: `BY_VEHICLE`, `BY_COLOR`, `BY_MAKER` - you switch these around to get desired perspective
- Iterate through the list of enums, collecting ALL entities specific to that enum value (cars, makers, colors) as objects or so. With a factory method, create a node using the `enumValue`, while passing the tree builder, and the `parentEnumValue` (for a top-level, the parent enum value is NULL).
- Child has a `getParentMember_Internal` which fetches the corect parent based on `parentEnumValue` (by using the `treeBuilder` which contains all the data mappings)
- In the previous iteration which I've mentioned, using the parent object of the resulting node, we can search through the tree and see which node it is (keep in mind levels are created top-down, so parents already exist)

**Why it doesn't work:**

- When searching for the correct parent, there may be several instances of it in the tree, so we are forced to look at the grandparent as well.
- Also, branches may be duplicated (see second tree)

**What I'm asking:**

- Is there a specific naming for this kinda of tree/algorithm? I couldn't think of an English term for this to use in Google.
- Does it have anything to do with a "K-D Tree"?
- Is there a generic way to do this sort of thing?

---

**EDIT 1 @Andreas**

There are only 3 possible entities in the tree: `Vehicle`, `Color`, `Maker`. There is not "vehicle type". All payloads in the tree are subclasses of these three.

I call them "payloads", because each object is wrapped in a `AbstractNode` subclass (which is part of a tree structure) to separate the data from the presentation layer. Example: `VehicleNode has a Vehicle payload`.

Since the entities are **independent** from eachother, levels may be hidden.
This would be a valid case:

```
|-- Green
|   |-- Audi
|   `-- BMW
|-- Blue
|   `-- Audi
|-- Red
|   |-- Audi
|   |-- BMW
|   `-- Honda
`-- Yellow
    |-- BMW (notice this doesn't appear twice under 'yellow', like in the second tree above)
    `-- Honda
```

Comment: I would try to use a stack and feed it with preorder, postorder and breathfirst iteration? Only quick idea....hmm but maybe this does not solve your problem you mentioned in "why it doesn't work"

Comment: You are suffering because you are trying to store your data in a tree structure, when in fact your data items aren't related to each other that way. I suggest you store your (vehicle, color, maker) triples without relation to each other, and then build your trees from there instead of trying to transform one tree to another.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, this is like a [Star Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema), used in Data Warehouse databases for [Online Analytical Processing (OLAP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing).

In your case, that would be a Fact table `Vehicle` and 3 Dimensions (`Type`, `Brand`, `Color`).

I'd suggest keeping the vehicles in a list, and build the 6 trees/indexes from the list, rather than trying to convert one tree to another.

A fully typed implementation might be to define a generic abstract tree:

```
public abstract class Tree<F, D1, D2, D3> {
    protected Tree(List<F> facts) {
        // code here using getDimensionN() to build tree
    }
    protected abstract D1 getDimension1(F fact);
    protected abstract D2 getDimension2(F fact);
    protected abstract D3 getDimension3(F fact);
    public List<F> get(D1 dimension1) {
        // code here
    }
    public List<F> get(D1 dimension1, D2 dimension2) {
        // code here
    }
    public List<F> get(D1 dimension1, D2 dimension2, D3 dimension3) {
        // code here
    }
    // other public accessor methods here
}
```

You can then construct a particular tree using code like:

```
List<F> facts = ...;
Tree<Vehicle, Type, Brand, Color> typeBrandColorTree = new Tree<Vehicle, Type, Brand, Color>(facts) {
    protected Type getDimension1(Vehicle vehicle) { return vehicle.getType(); }
    protected Brand getDimension2(Vehicle vehicle) { return vehicle.getBrand(); }
    protected Color getDimension3(Vehicle vehicle) { return vehicle.getColor(); }
};

// Use of tree
List<Vehicle> audiCars = typeBrandColorTree.get(Type.CAR, Brand.AUDI);
```

---

**Update**

The Star Schema may not be appropriate for your particular question, so this is more for information about Star Schemas. Let me use an example to illustrate what a Fact might be.

A fact could be the sale of a Vehicle, where the sale statistics being tracked includes:

- Type (Car, Bike)
- Brand (Audi, BMW, Honda)
- Color (Green, Blue, Red, Yellow)
- Date
- Price

The trees/indexes can then be used to answer questions like:

- Show sales of Audi Cars.
- How many Blue Bikes were sold?
- List total sales amount by Brand.

For faster access, the tree nodes could even have pre-aggregated values like `Count` and `TotalPrice`, such that you won't need to iterate all the facts to get your answers.

This is mainly used for *huge* data sets (e.g. 10 years of national sales data), to help managers get various summary statistics on-demand, fast. Hence the term "Online Analytical Processing".

Comment: In your answer, `Vehicle` and `Type` are one and the same thing for me. I don't quite get the `Fact` table, because my data structure doesn't have a "main" level (e.g. vehicle). The dimension are all connected to eachother, without any reference point.

Comment: It would be ever more awesome if you let `get` return a subtree instead of a list and allow arbitrary arguments. :)

Comment: @GGrec I might have been confused about the "has a payload" in the question. I was assuming that a `Vehicle` could have more properties than just the 3 dimensions, and that the trees were there for structured/ordered navigation and faster access of subset.

Comment: @RobAu Possibilities are there, e.g. rename `Tree` to `Tree3D` and have `Tree2D get(d1)`, `Tree1D get(d1, d2)`, and `List get(d1, d2, d3)`, all assuming that multiple vehicles are allowed for the same Type/Brand/Color combination.

Comment: @Andreas Edited my question. Can you please elaborate on that `Fact`? Also, can you eliminate the dependency to `Vehicle` from each entity?